# Tomcat 6: Max Session Idle time different between instances

Tags: java, http, session, tomcat

I am using HttpSession's with Tomcat 6. The first instance of Tomcat 6 that I deployed my web application in had the behavior I would expect for my Tomcat sessions (I set a maxInactiveInteval on my session to 30 minutes).

> **Update**: I added more code to the following to demonstrate exactly how I'm setting this timeout on a session

This is how I first setup the session:

```
session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(USER_CREDENTIALS, new Credentials(username, password));
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*30);
```

I then have an interceptor which checks this session:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
Credentials cred = (Credentials) session.getAttribute(AuthController.USER_CREDENTIALS);
```

Seems to work fine in the Tomcat instance I devloped with, but in another instance of Tomcat 6, in a load balanced environment, the  maxInactiveInteval doesn't seem to be respected.

> **Update:** What I mean is that the users session expires if the user is inactive (no new requests) for approximately ten seconds.

There is no where else in the code where  maxInactiveInteval is set. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Your question is confusing. The `setMaxInactiveInterval()` doesn't do what you think it does. It does basically exactly the same as `<session-timeout>`, only it allows to change it on a per-session basis, and thus that line which you've there to set exactly the same value is entirely superfluous. What exactly is the problem you're seeing and are trying to solve?

Comment: @BalusC noted, I was thinking the <session-timeout> was the time in minutes before your session is expired, but it appears it is the time a session is allowed to be idle between requests before it is invalidated.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I see that you've edited your question to remove this confusion. But I still don't understand your concrete problem. What *exactly* do you mean with "doesn't seem to be respected"? When/where are you setting this value and what happens instead?

Comment: @BalusC cool, I just updated.

Comment: Ah right, on a loadbalanced Tomcat instance, the session expires somewhat immediately when you set the timeout programmatically? And it does not happen when you don't do that? Sounds like a bug or a configuration issue. What Tomcat 6 version exactly? What is its default `<session-timeout>` set to?

Comment: @BalusC Setting the session expiry programmatic-ally was a reaction to the session's expiring immediately, but it didn't work. The instance where I do not see the issue is 6.0.20, and the instances where I see the issue are 6.0.33. The default session-timeout in conf/web.xml is set to 30 (minutes according to their comment). I also am not setting a default in the webapp's web.xml, but I did try, and that did not seem to work aswell.

Comment: Okay, your concrete problem is that a loadbalanced Tomcat instance expires the sessions almost immediately. The `<session-timeout>` and `setMaxInactiveInterval()` just don't help at all. How exactly did you conclude that it's Tomcat who's expiring the session (and it's thus not the client or some proxy or loadbalancer who don't pass the cookies forth and back)? Are you logging session creation and destroy with for example a `HttpSessionListener`? Have you tracked the cookie traffic with Firebug and/or Fiddler?

Comment: @BalusC I used Firebug and saw the correct cookie being passed around.

Comment: Okay, so the loadbalancer or Tomcat configuration is broken. This is food for the server admin. Or are there other webapps which works perfectly fine on the same environment?

Comment: @BalusC  it was Load balancer configuration that caused the problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Do you want me to repost the above as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on the question, your concrete problem is that a loadbalanced Tomcat instance expires the sessions almost immediately. Setting/changing the `<session-timeout>` and `setMaxInactiveInterval()` just don't help at all.

You first need to exclude the client from being suspect by tracking the cookie traffic using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and/or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com). If the cookie traffic looks fine (i.e. the client returns the proper session cookie on all subsequent requests), then the loadbalancer or Tomcat configuration is broken. This is not a programming error, but food for the server admin.